# MultiValueDictKeyError while updating inline formsets

Tags: python, django, inline-formset

I'm having an issue with Django while updating inline formsets. I want to update a form and an inline formset, but it raises this error:

```
"MultiValueDictKeyError"

Exception Value: "u'clientphone_set-0-id'"
```

This is my view:

```
def edit_client(request, client_id):

    client_to_edit = Client.objects.get(id=client_id)
    form = ClientForm(instance=client_to_edit)
    phone_formset = ClientPhoneFormSet(instance=client_to_edit)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClientForm(request.POST, instance=client_to_edit)

        if form.is_valid():
            form_saved = form.save(commit=False)
            phone_formset = ClientPhoneFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=form_saved)

            if phone_formset.is_valid():
                form_saved.save()
                phone_formset.save()        
                return client(request)

    return render(request, 'WorkOrders/add_client.html', {'form' : form, 'phone_formset' : phone_formset})
```

And these are my forms

```
class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128)
    rif = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=250)

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('name','rif','address',)

ClientPhoneFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Client, ClientPhone, extra=1, fields=('phone_number',), can_delete=True)
```

And this is my template

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="add_client" method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <div class="form-group">
           <label for="{{ field.id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ field.help_text }}</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
             {{ field.errors }}
             {{ field }}
           </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ field.id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Teléfono</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    {% for form in phone_formset.forms %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {% if form.instance.pk %}
                                    {{ form.DELETE }}
                                {% endif %}
                                {{ form.errors }}
                                {{ form.phone_number }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
{{ phone_formset.management_form }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
            <a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Volver</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

It opens the form with no problem, the error happens when I submit.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have twice the same field in your form, by any chance?

Comment: I guess you should show your form.py here

Comment: How are you rendering the formset in your template?

Comment: @nnaelle Yes, they appear 2 times because when I enter into the "update" view, it automatically adds a new field.

Comment: @Ladmerc Yes, I'm adding it here, I forgot to add it before, sorry.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper There I added my template, thanks.

Comment: @RogerGonzalez is it on purpuse that you don't have a `<form>` tag? Is your model saying that a client should only have one phone number (`ForeignKey` instead of `ManyToMany`)  ?

Comment: @nnaelle I have a '<form>' tag in the beginning of the template. I just forgot to add the '</form>' in the question, I'm going to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by using `phone_formset` instead of `phone_formset.forms`, and added the `{{ phone_field.id }}`.

Here is the result:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        {% for phone_field in phone_formset %}
        <tr>
           <td>
              {% if phone_field.instance.pk %}
                {{ phone_field.DELETE }}
              {% endif %}
              {{ phone_field.errors }}
              {{ phone_field.id }}
              {{ phone_field.phone_number }}
           </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```